# How do I implement `.or()` for `Future<Option>`?

Tags: rust, future, opaque-types

I'm trying to implement `.or` for futures: return the same `Option` if `result.is_some()` and another `Option` type otherwise:

```rust
trait FutureOr {
    type Output;

    fn or(self, f: Self::Output) -> Self::Output;
}

impl <Fut, T> FutureOr for Fut where Fut: std::future::Future<Output = Option<T>> {
    type Output = Fut;

    fn or(self, f: Fut) -> Self::Output {

        self.then(|res| match res {
            Some(res) => async { Some(res) },
            None => async { f.await }
        })
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't compile:

```
`match` arms have incompatible types
expected opaque type `impl futures::Future<Output = std::option::Option<T>>` (`async` block)
   found opaque type `impl futures::Future<Output = std::option::Option<T>>` (`async` block)
```

Obviously, the types are the same, but from what I gather, the compiler is complaining about the fact that the `opaque` types might differ, i.e. the runtime type the generic will assume (?), could differ.
So how can I indicate to the compiler I don't need their opaque types to differ?

I tried to:

- return the Future of the second match arm directly instead of wrapping it in an async block, and wrapping the first arm with `std::future::ready()`, but to my surprise this doesn't return a `std::future::Future` but a `std::future::Ready`, incompatible with the `Future`;
- wrapping the match statement in an async block, thus avoiding having two different concrete futures there, but the compiler warn this does not return a `Future` but a `Then<Future>`, and I don't know how to collect that into a `Future` (`into_future()` does not help, still returns `Then<Future>`, but why?).

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bc8ad743122f8f2e0eec904ca6aea3b0)

---

UPDATE: OK, I think I am [almost there](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=61eafa294ac9cfb52c24803746d70fa1). Compiler doesn't want the types to be `impl`:

```
error: unconstrained opaque type
  --> src/main.rs:19:15
   |
19 |     type Or = impl std::future::Future<Output = Option<T>>;
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `Or` must be used in combination with a concrete type within the same module
```

---

UPDATE: Could get rid of `impl` by having generics, but compiler [doesn't like that either](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2ed9646ab36fc28f734c7cd796388a64):

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `OrFut` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:15:11
   |
15 | impl<Fut, OrFut, OutFut, T> FutureOr for Fut
   |           ^^^^^ unconstrained type parameter

error[E0207]: the type parameter `OutFut` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:15:18
   |
15 | impl<Fut, OrFut, OutFut, T> FutureOr for Fut
   |                  ^^^^^^ unconstrained type parameter
```

Maybe I need to move the implementation to the function, trying that now...

---

UPDATE: [Closest I could come](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e720b06b155a44857d562146b2596ba2). Only thing that seems left is understanding how to return a `Future` instead of a `AndThen<Future>`. This can probably be resolved by using the `async_trait` crate, letting the crate do the async de-sugaring for us, but I don't want to pull that in just because of a single method trait...

Comment: Your playground says: "no method named `then` found for type parameter `Fut` in the current scope".

Comment: @rodrigo it was lacking one trait import, updated now

Comment: You cannot do what you want, because you are returning two different types. You can imagine that each async block is compiled to an anonymous structure that implements the `Future` trait.  So in the `Some()` case you are returning `struct Anon1` and in the `None` case - `struct Anon2`. Obviously each  function has 1 return type, but you have 2 types, so it's not possible to do it like that. If you want to return either A or B, you can use boxed futures instead of associated types, or if you do not want to use heap allocations - return an enum

Comment: Thanks, I might try with an enum. 

Two points: 

If the issue here is the two async blocks, then I imagine my 2nd try `(|res| match res { async {...}}).into_future()`might solve it, but somehow this doesn't do what advertises and still returns a `Then<Future>`.

2. The fact that rust has to create two structures, doesn't break the type-safety here: the two different structures will still have the same type, I'll be have to call the same methods on it, they'll have the same size: what is actually wrong here that rust does not allow it?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev inspired by your answer, I tried to give the compiler more flexibility of picking the types by separating the input, output, and parameter. They don't compile for different unrelated reasons to the above.
Could you give those a second look? They're in the question updates. Thanks!

Comment: Usually this is simple enough to fix by wrapping the `match` in an `async` block: `|res| async { match res { Some(v) => Some(v), None => f.await } }`. You'll still have the associated type problem though; that'll require returning a boxed future until `impl` return types work on traits.

Comment: @cdhowie they’re available in nightly behind a flag, however it still doesn’t work, see  my first update with included playground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, your code is trying to treat two different futures (`f`, and the return value of `fn or()`) as the same type (`Self::Output`). This can't work, because every distinct *implementation* of `Future` is a different type. And, as you already discovered, it's not possible to name the type of an `async` block in a way that's useful for traits (until `type_alias_impl_trait` is stabilized).

Here is a rewrite that uses boxed futures, the usual workaround for TAIT. We carefully distinguish between the 3 future types: `Self`, `Other`, and the returned future.

```rust
use futures::{future::BoxFuture, Future};

trait FutureOr: Future + 'static {
    fn or<Other>(self, f: Other) -> BoxFuture<'static, Self::Output>
    where
        Other: Future<Output = Self::Output> + Send + 'static;
}

impl<Fut, T> FutureOr for Fut
where
    T: Send + 'static,
    Fut: std::future::Future<Output = Option<T>> + Send + 'static,
{
    fn or<Other>(self, f: Other) -> BoxFuture<'static, Self::Output>
    where
        Other: Future<Output = Self::Output> + Send + 'static,
    {
        Box::pin(async {
            match self.await {
                Some(res) => Some(res),
                None => f.await,
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The `Send + 'static` bounds are unfortunately needed since boxed futures have to pick a specific choice of lifetime and `Send`-or-`!Send`.

Once we have `type_alias_impl_trait` in a future stable version of Rust, we can avoid the boxing and the extra bounds:

```rust
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]
use std::future::Future;

trait FutureOr<Other>: Future
where
    Other: Future<Output = Self::Output>,
{
    type Ored: Future<Output = Self::Output>;

    fn or(self, f: Other) -> Self::Ored;
}

type OptOred<Fut, Other, T>
where
    Fut: Future<Output = Option<T>>,
= impl Future<Output = Option<T>>;

impl<Fut, Other, T> FutureOr<Other> for Fut
where
    Fut: std::future::Future<Output = Option<T>>,
    Other: std::future::Future<Output = Self::Output>,
{
    type Ored = OptOred<Fut, Other, T>;

    fn or(self, f: Other) -> Self::Ored {
        async {
            match self.await {
                Some(res) => Some(res),
                None => f.await,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`type Ored` is a special type alias which gets assigned the type of the `async` block future in `fn or()` *because* we returned that future from a function whose return type is that type alias. Note that `Other` now has to be a type parameter on the trait so that `type Ored` can refer to it, whereas in the first version the details were hidden inside `dyn Future` and `Other` didn't need to be mentioned.

Finally, we can still have a clean generic `FutureOr` on stable, at the price of *manually writing a future.* In this case, I've chosen to use the `pin_project` library to avoid this needing any newly written `unsafe` code, but it's still fairly complex:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

trait FutureOr<Other>: Future
where
    Other: Future<Output = Self::Output>,
{
    type Ored: Future<Output = Self::Output>;

    fn or(self, f: Other) -> Self::Ored;
}

impl<Fut, Other, T> FutureOr<Other> for Fut
where
    Fut: std::future::Future<Output = Option<T>>,
    Other: std::future::Future<Output = Self::Output>,
{
    type Ored = OptOred<Fut, Other>;

    fn or(self, b: Other) -> Self::Ored {
        OptOred {
            skip_a: false,
            a: self,
            b,
        }
    }
}

#[pin_project::pin_project]
struct OptOred<A, B> {
    skip_a: bool,
    #[pin]
    a: A,
    #[pin]
    b: B,
}

impl<A, B, T> Future for OptOred<A, B>
where
    A: Future<Output = Option<T>>,
    B: Future<Output = Option<T>>,
{
    type Output = A::Output;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, context: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<<Self as Future>::Output> {
        let proj = self.project();
        if !*proj.skip_a {
            match proj.a.poll(context) {
                Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
                r @ Poll::Ready(Some(_)) => r,
                Poll::Ready(None) => {
                    *proj.skip_a = true; // don't poll `a` again
                    proj.b.poll(context)
                }
            }
        } else {
            proj.b.poll(context)
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code, only checked that it compiles.

Comment: Beautiful! Any resources/exercises to learn/practice this kind of abstract type composition?

Comment: @doplumi I don't have any resources to recommend, sorry. The best advice I can think of is to practice thinking mathematically; the perspective "what is the most general thing I can write that has the properties I need?" And, when the compiler gives you an error, don't just approach that from "how can I not have an error", but "what does this actually mean about the properties of my program and the rules of the language?" Consult documentation to learn those rules further, and you can build a good mental model of **what is possible** (and thus the most general that is possible).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get this to work today on stable Rust *without* boxing the returned future is to implement your own future.  This is a bit of work, mostly due to pinning gymnastics.  We need an additional generic type to represent the type of the provided "default value" future -- using `Self::Output` won't work because you're wanting to call this method with *any* type of future, but `Self::Output` is the type of future produced by `or()`.

This type parameter has to go on the trait itself and not the `or` method, because the type will be used as part of the `Output` associated type in the implementation.

```
trait FutureOr<FDef> {
    type Output;

    fn or(self, f: FDef) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Our custom future type needs an instance of `Self` and `FDef`.  Once `Self` has produced a value and if that value is `None`, we need to switch to polling the provided `f` future instead, so we need a way to signal to ourselves that the `Self` future has been polled to completion.  We'll do this by wrapping it in an `Option`.

```
struct FutureOrFuture<T, F, FDef>
where F: Future<Output=Option<T>>,
    FDef: Future<Output=Option<T>>
{
    fut: Option<F>,
    def: FDef,
}
```

For the pinning gymnastics, we need a way to map `Pin<&mut Self>` to pinned wrappers around these fields.  We'll write some helpers to make this ergonomic within `poll()`.

```
impl<T, F, FDef> FutureOrFuture<T, F, FDef>
where F: Future<Output=Option<T>>,
    FDef: Future<Output=Option<T>>
{
    fn get_fut(self: Pin<&mut Self>) -> Option<Pin<&mut F>> {
        unsafe { self.get_unchecked_mut() }.fut.as_mut()
            .map(|r| unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(r) })
    }
    
    fn get_def(self: Pin<&mut Self>) -> Pin<&mut FDef> {
        unsafe { self.map_unchecked_mut(|v| &mut v.def) }
    }
}
```

Finally, we can implement `Future`.  We'll poll `fut` when it's `Some`, falling back on `def` otherwise.

```
impl<T, F, FDef> Future for FutureOrFuture<T, F, FDef>
where F: Future<Output=Option<T>>,
    FDef: Future<Output=Option<T>>
{
    type Output = Option<T>;
    
    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, ctx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        match self.as_mut().get_fut() {
            Some(fut) => match fut.poll(ctx) {
                Poll::Ready(None) => {
                    // Clear self.fut; it's now consumed.
                    unsafe { self.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut() }.fut = None;
                    self.get_def().poll(ctx)
                },
                // Pending and Ready(Some(_))
                v => v,
            }
            None => self.get_def().poll(ctx)
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `or()` implementation just delegates to this future type.

```
impl<Fut, T, FDef> FutureOr<FDef> for Fut
where Fut: Future<Output=Option<T>>,
    FDef: Future<Output=Option<T>>
{
    type Output = FutureOrFuture<T, Self, FDef>;

    fn or(self, f: FDef) -> Self::Output {
        FutureOrFuture { fut: Some(self), def: f }
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=be11ec49aaa303bb473a7f182f8ad10c))

---

Alternatively, if you can live with the overhead of boxing, the whole thing becomes a bit simpler since you can use `.await` -- but then you have to futz around with lifetimes.  (You don't have to in the approach given above because any lifetimes are part of the generic type arguments of the resulting future type, so those lifetimes flow through by themselves.  Boxing erases the compile-time types and so we have to do some work to get the lifetimes properly communicated.)

Note that this approach (returning a pinned box with lifetimes sprinkled in) is exactly what `async_trait` does for you.

The "incompatible match arms" issue is resolved here by wrapping the whole `match` block in `async` and awaiting `f` inside of it.

```
trait FutureOr {
    fn or<'a, 'b, 'c, 'd, T>(self, f: impl Future<Output=Self::Output> + Send + 'a)
    -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Option<T>> + Send + 'd>>
    where T: Send + 'b,
        Self: Future<Output=Option<T>> + Send + 'c,
        'a: 'd,
        'b: 'd,
        'c: 'd;
}

impl<Fut> FutureOr for Fut {
    fn or<'a, 'b, 'c, 'd, T>(self, f: impl Future<Output=<Self as Future>::Output> + Send + 'a)
    -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Option<T>> + Send + 'd>>
    where T: Send + 'b,
        Self: Future<Output=Option<T>> + Send + 'c,
        'a: 'd,
        'b: 'd,
        'c: 'd
    {
        Box::pin(self.then(|res| async move {
            match res {
                Some(res) => Some(res),
                None => f.await,
            }
        }))
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0376ee328a16d30e42bb814b7498b419))